# How to set the value of select option

Tags: jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate the dropdown menu based on the selection of the first menu. using the code below it will just make the next dropdown to be empty

```
  $(\".category_id\").change(function(){

    $(\"#account_id > option\").remove();
    $(\"#item_name_id > option\").remove();

    var  category_id={'category_id':$(this).val()};

 $.ajax({
       type: \"POST\",
       url: 'getCategory1/', 
       dataType: \"json\",
       data: category_id,
       success: function(category_ids){ 

 // category_ids = {"0":"Choose Account Name","2":"OfficeEquipment","3":"IT Equipment"}
               $.each(category_ids,function(account_id,name){

                  var opt = $('<option />');           
                  opt.val(account_id);
                  opt.text(name);

                  $(this).closest('td').next().find('select').append(opt);

             });
          }

      });
});
```

The controller function I used:

```
  public function actionGetCategory1(){
        //Get all the sub categories a the main category
        $cat_id = $_POST['category_id'];
        $subCategory = Item::model()->getCategory1($cat_id); 
        echo(json_encode($subCategory));
    }
```

The model function

```
public function getCategory1($cat_id){
        $where  = "WHERE category_id = $cat_id";
        $select = "SELECT * FROM tbl_account $where";
        $query  =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand($select)->queryAll();

        $subCat = array();
        $subCat[0] = "Choose Account Name";
           if($query){
              foreach($query as $row){
                $subCat[$row['account_id']] = $row['account_name'];
              }
              return $subCat;
            }
            else{ return FALSE; }
    }
```

The data to be loop in the $.each will be coming form the controller in json format. I used var_dump to display i.

```
string(189) "{"0":"Choose Account Name","2":"Information and Communication Technology Equipment","3":"Office Equipment","4":"Furniture and Fixtures","5":"Communication Equipment","6":"Other Equipments"}"
```

[image: Dropdown Form]

Comment: Is your selector returning anything? Can you include your html? Maybe even a jsfiddle. I think your selector is incorrect. $(this) inside the $.each is not going to be what you want.

Comment: Yes if I used $(this) inside the $.each it will result to undefined but if I used it outside the $.each it will give a result not undefined.

Comment: where is the ajax call placed... is it inside a event handler

Comment: It is triggered onan  onchange event of another dropdown menu

Comment: Are you trying to build cascading dropdown menus and want to stack up the options on the next select boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this. You will need to use a better selector for getting your < select > tag.

```
$.each(category_ids,function(account_id,name){
    var x = document.createElement('option');
    x.setAttribute('value', account_id);
    var y = document.createTextNode(name);
    $(x).append(y);

    $('#selectId').append(x)
});
```

**EDIT**
After further discussion this looks like a better answer:

```
$(\".category_id\").change(function(){
    var _this = this;
    $(\"#account_id > option\").remove();
    $(\"#item_name_id > option\").remove();

    var  category_id={'category_id':$(this).val()};

 $.ajax({
       type: \"POST\",
       url: 'getCategory1/', 
       dataType: \"json\",
       data: category_id,
       success: function(category_ids){ 

 // category_ids = {"0":"Choose Account Name","2":"OfficeEquipment","3":"IT Equipment"}
               $.each(category_ids,function(account_id,name){

                  var opt = $('<option />');           
                  opt.val(account_id);
                  opt.text(name);

                  $(_this).closest('td').next().find('select').append(opt);

             });
          }

      });
});
```

This is something that trips up a lot of people. Here is a good quick read on "this" scope that should make this clearer to understand.http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Comment: Yes it works it that way if only one set of fields is involve but in my case where in there are multiple row of fields it is not applicable that's why I used the $(this) in jquery.

Comment: I don't think $(this) is what you think it is. What do you get if you do a console.log($(this)); at that point?

Comment: Would also help to have an idea what the page DOM looks like

Comment: ''[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0], context: undefined, selector: "select option[0]", jquery: "1.9.0", constructor: function…]'' that is the result when I console it.

Comment: It looks like $(this) is probably referring to the each loop function. Like I said previously, you will need to find a better way to target the select element. Without knowing more about the code it is near impossible to debug this. How is this ajax call being fired and what does the page DOM look like?

Comment: Right after you open enter the 'change' function (line 2) add this line... var _this = this;  ...Now you will have a referrence to the original calling object in _this. So later in your each you should be able to... $(_this).closest('td').next().find('select').append(opt);

Comment: Thank you it did worked, it populated the next dropdown menu with the data I needed. nice :D

Comment: The dropdown menu is now populated but these codes make it empty. How can the codes below be also dynamic using the "this"' variable? $(\"#account_id > option\").remove();    $(\"#item_name_id > option\").remove();'

Comment: You are targeting objects by their ID, this cannot be dynamic. You would have to target them by class name or position in the DOM. Assuming that the #account_id is the next select and has a class of account_id, you could do this.. `$(_this).closest('td').next().find('select.account_id  > option').remove();` ... Just be careful of where you put this, if it is in the each loop you will removing them as you are putting them in.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
    $.each(category_ids,function(account_id,name){
      var opt = $('<option />');           
      opt.val(account_id);
      opt.text(name);
      $(this).closest('td').next().find('select').append(opt);
    });
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('select option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: That can't be right. Inside a $.each, this will not refer to a DOM element.

Comment: How can I solved it the code above returns thesame result undefine in console. '[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0], context: undefined, selector: "select option[0]", jquery: "1.9.0", constructor: function…]'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to build up cascading dropdown menus. A user has to select the category first, account name next, and so on... am I right?

If that's what you want. Your code is not right unless those cascading dropdownmenus are going to have only one option each.

```
$.ajax({
   type: \"POST\",
   url: 'getCategory1/', 
   dataType: \"json\",
   data: category_id,
   success: function(category_ids){ 
       // assume that your category_ids will be a string array.
       // ex: ["#cate01", "#cate02", "#cate03", "#cate04", "#cate05"]  

       $.each(category_ids, function(account_id,name) {
           // first loop,
           //   be account_id = 0, name = "#cate01"

           var opt = $('<option />');           
           opt.val(account_id);
           opt.text(name);

           // <option value="0">#cate01</option> is created.

           // this will be "#cate01", it is the same with the name value.
           // actually, you don't need to use this keyword here.
           $(this).closest('td').next().find('select').append(opt);

           // it will look up #cate01 and find its parent, its td and
           // moves to td right next to it, and finally settles on the select element inside it.
       });
   }

});
```

With this code, the options will not stack up on a select element **because the target selecbox keeps changing during the whole each loop.** I suspect that there's more on `category_ids`. But even if `category_ids consist of more than a string array, it's not the way to do it. I feel uncertain to continue my answer, because it seems that you are smart enough to know already how to tweak this kind of code.

Anyway..

```
$.ajax({
       type: \"POST\",
       url: 'getCategory1/', 
       dataType: \"json\",
       data: category_id,
       success: function(category_ids){ 

           $.each(category_ids, function(account_id,name) {

               // you need a list of option data here, 
               // fetching it though AJAX or something ( it's your call )

               // Let's say you get a set of option data like this at this point.
               /* 
                    optData : { 
                       cate01 : ["option01", "option02", "option03" ··· , "option10" ]
                    }
               */

               // I'm declaring this variable for improving readability.
               var targetDropdown = $(name).closest('td').next().find('select');
               $.each(optData.cate01, function(val, optionName) {
                   var opt = $('<option />');           
                   opt.val(val);
                   opt.text(optionName).appendTo(targetDropdown);
               }

           });
       }

    });
```

**FYI**

I don't know what kind of data you are trying to put into each select boxes and what kind of data you actually have, **but the point is that your current code is not able to pile up the options on a single select box.**

I just suggested the way to acheive the goal. If you provide me the exact set of data, I mean the options, I can help you more precisely. I guess this is enough for you by the way.